# Thumbnail storage

Tags: geonetwork

Currently GeoNetwork stores Thumbnails  (at least in my latest version) on the computer and not where the XML metadata is stored.
my question: is there a way to store Thumbnails  (pictures) in a database (same for the XML metadata) ?
thanks
Abel

Answer (score 1):

No, this functionality is not available in GeoNetwork, at least not yet in 3.6.0 version or next 3.8.0.